# Unexpected Token ILLEGAL on Javascript For Loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop, syntax-error

I'm attempting to write a simple randomizer that will randomly set group's background position individually.

HTML:

```
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background:url(redMetal.jpg) no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
    for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
        x = Math.random() * (3499 - 0) + 0;
        y = Math.random() * (2359 - 0) + 0;
        button[i].style.backgroundPosition =  (x * -1) + "px" + (y * -1) + "px";
        button[i].innerHTML = i;
    }​
```

When I do this, I get an UNCAUGHT SYNTAXERROR: Unexpected token ILLEGAL right after the closing curly brace of the for loop, and I don't understand why.

Comment: That's because you have an illegal character immediately after the closing curly brace. [Represented by the red dot here.](http://jsfiddle.net/s4mc18zu/2/). Note that I copied this code direct from your question.

Comment: Is this all of your JavaScript, or is there anything after the for loop?

Comment: The code looks valid. Maybe you have some invisible and invalid character at the end of your script.

Comment: this is 100% of my javascript, there is nothing after the for loop.  I double checked and made to delete any arrant non-breaking spaces, and it's clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have an illegal character after the last curly brace, see what i got [copy-pasting that code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eL0bjhrs/), notice the red dot.

```
    button[i].innerHTML = i;
}​*
```

Open that file with another editor, e.g. vim an check for weird characters with `:set list`.

Comment: I saw it too, after pasting it into jFiddle. thank you.

Comment: Murphy, rewriting the last lines could be the only way to remove that character...

Comment: which I did... I'm marking this as the correct answer.. I just have to wait until the site lets me.

Comment: And about how that non printable character got there, something similar (lost one afternoon to understand this) happened to me while doing webdev, using nginx on a vagrant vm...